# Import Microsoft Word AutoText to LibreOffice

Tags: import, ms-word, libreoffice-writer, buildingblocks

Is it possible to import the Microsoft Word AutoText file (apparently called "building blocks.dotm") to LibreOffice? If yes, how?

Background information:

- [AutoText seems to be part of Building Blocks](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/quick-parts-vs-auto-text/08ab4fc9-e21d-4657-8f6f-aeecc353e81f);
- [OpenOffice seems to already have tackled the issue](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Migration_Guide/Importing_Files), but it doesn't work when I try with LibreOffice, the latter does not "see" the file (neither "building blocks.dotm" or "building blocks.dot", nor "Normal.dotm" or "Normal.dot").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools -> AutoText and then under the AutoText dropdown button, click Import.
[image]

LibreOffice expects a Word document or template (.doc or .dot) that contains AutoText. 
[image]
Documentation is at https://help.libreoffice.org/index.php?title=Writer/AutoText#Import.

Comment: Thanks @Jim K.
So if I understand correctly, LibreOffice won't be able to import .dotm files, correct?

Comment: Well, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Office_filename_extensions) says that .dotm is a Word 2007 and later format.  According to the link and picture in my answer, LibreOffice expects Word 2003 and earlier formats.